# Different regions for Firestore DB and Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to know that once I created the Firestore database in a region where Cloud Functions are not available, Can I setup cloud functions in a different region where it is available ?
and if can, Any comment on the latency ?

(Because the region I am targeting has no cloud function within the region, I want to use them from a nearby region other than using multi-region.)

Answer (score 4):

You can have the database and functions in different regions.

Latency is something you'll have to benchmark on your own based on the specific regions you've chosen.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. want to know the latency would be critically high than both in the same region.

Comment: Again, that's something you can test for yourself for the regions you've chosen.